# Reporting Query to use in Klipfolio for 3 levels deep case hierarcy

Tags: soql, reporting, hierarchy, force.com-explorer

**- I have a 3 levels deep case hierarchy:**

```
Case level 1 (1.createdate, 1.closedate, 1.type, 1.subtype)
|
+---> Case level 2 (2.createdate, 2.closedate, 2.type, 2.subtype)
      |
      +---> Case level 3 (3.createdate, 3.closedate, 3.type, 3.subtype)
```

**- want to create a SOQL query to use in Klipfolio that shows:**

1.createdate, 1.closedate, 1.type, 1.subtype, 2.createdate, 2.closedate, 3.createdate, 3.closedate

Query underneath works... but only one level deep...

SELECT 
     CaseNumber
,    Type
,    Sub_type__c
,    CreatedDate
,    ClosedDate
,    Duration_min__c
,    Status
,    Overall_Process_Status__c
,    (SELECT 
           CaseNumber
     ,     Type
     ,     Sub_type__c
     ,     CreatedDate
     ,     ClosedDate
     ,     Duration_min__c
     ,     Status
     ,     Overall_Process_Status__c 
     FROM 
           Cases 
     WHERE 
           Type='DBA') 
FROM 
    Case 
WHERE 
    Casenumber = '00133138'

Comment: What is the SOQL you are trying and what error do you receive? This would be helpful information.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your quick reply. I'm used to sql so need to readjust to SOQL...

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your quick reply. I'm used to sql so need to readjust to SOQL... SELECT CaseNumber, Type, Sub_type__c, CreatedDate, ClosedDate, Duration_min__c, Status, Overall_Process_Status__c, (SELECT CaseNumber, Type, Sub_type__c, CreatedDate, ClosedDate, Duration_min__c, Status, Overall_Process_Status__c FROM Cases WHERE Type='DBA') FROM Case WHERE Casenumber = '00133138' works... but is top down and thus only 1 level deep max... tried other statements from stackexhange but get 'unexpected token 'set''trying  (http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14213/account-soql-traverse)

Comment: Do you have a custom field on Case that is a recursive lookup back to Case?

Comment: Please update your question with the updated information. This will make the SOQL more legible (i.e. you can format it) and make it easier to provide an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SOQL, you generally have to go up instead of down, so the appropriate SOQL would be something like:

```
SELECT Id, CaseNumber, Type, Sub_type__c, CreatedDate, ClosedDate, Duration_min__c, 
       Status, Overall_Process_Status__c, Parent.Id, Parent.CaseNumber, Parent.Type, 
       Parent.Sub_type__c, Parent.CreatedDate, Parent.ClosedDate, 
       Parent.Duration_min__c, Parent.Status, Parent.Overall_Process_Status__c, 
       Parent.Parent.Id, Parent.Parent.CaseNumber, Parent.Parent.Type, 
       Parent.Parent.Sub_type__c, Parent.Parent.CreatedDate, Parent.Parent.ClosedDate, 
       Parent.Parent.Duration_min__c, Parent.Parent.Status, 
       Parent.Parent.Overall_Process_Status__c 
FROM Case 
WHERE Parent.Parent.CaseNumber = '00133138' OR 
      Parent.CaseNumber = '00133138' OR
      CaseNumber = '00133138'
```

This will find all cases where case number is 00133138, the parent case is 00133138, or the parent's parent case is 00133138.

You can go through four levels of relationships. You may need to map "duplicate" rows so that you get a full picture of the data. Without much experience with Klipfolio, I can't really speculate how or if this data set would be supported, but this is how you'd write a single SOQL query.

Comment: Thanks! I new it must be something 'easy'. This did the trick. Thanks again!